# EURO glyph [€] not shown in freetype

Tags: c++, opengl, freetype, text-rendering

I have been using freetype for quite a while now, I can display foreign character such as `âãäæë` etc. but I cannot display the Euro glyph.

I am using `Arial.ttf` font family.

In windows I saw a weird combination of the characters such as à≥ , and on mac the nothing was rendered.

is it the specific font family which doesn't have this character? Or is there any special function of freetype that i do not know about?

Comment: tried to ask on freetype.org forums?

Comment: no, but it would b a good place to look, thanks.